# Correct ADAL package for B2C - Xamarin PCL project

Tags: azure, xamarin, adal

I have read several articles on adding Azure Active Directory sign-in functionality to Xamarin PCL projects (e.g. https://blog.xamarin.com/put-adal-xamarin-forms/) but I am still not able to make it work.

Can someone please clarifiy the correct ADAL package to use for Azure B2C AD(for Xamarin PCL project)?

Is it:

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

OR

Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Kaush and @vibronet for pointing me in the right direction, saving a lot of time.

For anyone wanting to add B2C Sign-In & Sign-Up flows to a Xamarin Forms project - I was able to mash-up a solution for Android as follows:

1. At all times change any reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory to Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
2. Add the Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory package to all projects. If a compatibility error occurs in the PCL project then manually add a package reference using 'Add Reference' as described by @Kaush. I chose the 'portable-net45+win+wpa81' library.
3. Implement the flows as described here: https://blog.xamarin.com/put-adal-xamarin-forms/
4. Change the call to 'AcquireTokenAsync' to:

var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(new string[] { clientId }, null, clientId, new Uri(returnUri), platformParams, "{Policy_Name_Here}");

Notes:

1. Ensure the format of the authority is 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant_Name_Here}.onmicrosoft.com'
2. This is experimental based on alpha code so expect it to change / break / evolve in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.**Experimental**.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory is the right package for B2C, but the Xamarin scenario wasn't one targeted by this preview. We'll be adding new platforms as we refresh the preview going forward.

Comment: Hi Vittorio,

Thanks for the information. From the other platform articles (e.g. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-native-dotnet/) - I can see that the process is similar to ADAL v3 libraries.

FYI - trying to add the experimental package to a PCL project using package manager yields the 'package compatibility' error message.

Looking forward to Xamarin support!

Scott.

Answer (score 0):

I would pay heed to what @vibronet says, but having said that (and to get you going), here's my screen shot of all the references that I use in the sample project you mentioned:

[image: Snapshot of my references]

The ADAL package version I used was: 3.5.207081303-alpha (Prerelease), nuget did not add it to my PCL library, I ended up adding the reference explicitly via the 'Add Reference' and browsing to the package, maybe you could try the same.

Lastly, I had to add the extraQueryParameters as specified in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32971457/2869304)

Let me know how you go...