# Can not install the packages in Xamarin Studio on Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am newbee on Xamarin. I have created a Xamarin.Forms project with iOS and Android platforms. I am trying to add Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory package but getting following error `Could not install package 'Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 4.0.209160138-alpha'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+win+wp80+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarintvos10+xamarinwatchos10+xamarinios10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct ADAL package for B2C - Xamarin PCL project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028388/correct-adal-package-for-b2c-xamarin-pcl-project)

Comment: Hey @GeraldVersluis I followed the steps but Still the packages are not added.